# Auto detect column types in OpenCSV

Tags: scala, opencsv

I'm reading a file with OpenCSV this way (in Scala):

```
val reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"))
for (row <- reader.readAll) {
    println("col(0): " + row(0) + " col(1)" + row(1) )
}
```

Since the file was provided by a user, I don't know its format, but I need to know each column type (number, string, etc.). Is this possible with OpenCSV ? If not, is there another library that can auto detect column types?

Comment: There is no column type in CSV files. Everything is a string.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23656672/736957